# netbeans java se swing components' look switch to the old

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel, nimbus

I am using NetBeans 7.2.1, I want to create a Java SE Frame with Panels, swing components.
At the begining, my program's swing components are "beautiful", by the NimbusLookAndFeal. I didn't have to setup anything about it, it was working at the begining.
After a while, now the components look like the old.
Why is that? Why does my NetBeans change his mind, and doesn't show the nimbuslookandfeel?
I know that I can write a code to get the nimbuslookandfeel, but I don't want, because it was working at the begining, and I can't figurate out why does my NetBeans change after a while.
Please Help!

Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload a code or screenshot? "After a while, now the components look like the old." Specify "old".

Comment: this is the "old": http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/NimbusLookandFeel_OBE2012/images/t20104.gif

Comment: Ok, now upload code. As shortest as posible...

Comment: I answered it! :D thanks anyway

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figurate it out!
I always delete every comment in the Frames and Panels when I generate them, and in the Frame class, in the main method, the comment contains the nimbuslookandfeel settings!
The 16. picture showes it:
[link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/NimbusLookandFeel_OBE2012/CustomizingLandF.html)

Comment: Deleting a comment affects your look-and-feel ... somehow I doubt that

Comment: yehhh, I am crazy, and you are the best!!!! :D:D see the LINK!!!! you know what is link, right? And maybe you can understand what you're reading, at the end: "The 16. picture showes it" in the link! :) thank you for your incomprehension.